# Facebook Graph API in workplace: Group post - No notifications, not appear in news feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

I created a publishing bot for group in WorkPlace that creates a post once a day. In group setting I and other members have "Nofity me about All posts". 
I used group/feed path in Graph API to post a message in group

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{group_id}/feed
patameters: message=TestMessage
```

Message succesfully posts on group wall. But group members don't get any notifications about post. But they get it if member of a group posts a message.
Message also doesn't appear on news feed.

What I can do to make Workplace send notification about new post made by bot and put it on news feed?
On [documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/integrations/custom-integrations/bots/#botsingroups)  there is a picture of bot's post showing in news feed, so it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the behaviour is the same, if you are posting as user or with a bot. I would suggest you to open a bug to Workplace, providing the information about the wrong behaviour.